# "Bad Address" error when executing copy_to_user from a Linux kernel module

Tags: linux, module, kernel

I am implementing a kernel module (version 2.6.32) that can write to /proc, and allows writing and reading from/to the user space and kernel space. My write to kernel space code is working perfectly, but when trying to copy_to_user, I get a message that it has a "bad address".

I am running `echo "test" > procmodule` (the name of my module) and `cat procmodule` to retrieve the string from the module memory. The result of the second command is

> cat: procmodule: Bad address

Below is the relevant code:

```
int read_info( char *page , char **start, off_t off, int count, int *eof, void *data) {    
    if(copy_to_user(page, info, count)){
     return -EFAULT;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Page is the address of the user buffer, and info is the char array that currently holds the string I want to print. Count is the length of this string.

What I've tried:

- Printing the "info" string, it prints what I want to see so the array is not the issue
- Printing "page", the pointer exists
- Changing the permissions of the module in create_proc_entry, still has an error
- Returning 0, the size of the array itself, and the result of copy_to_user (which is the buffer size which was written, should be the same as count) at the end of the function, same error. If relevant, copy_to_user returns 3072

Any help would be greatly appreciated, please let me know if I'm missing anything obvious (much googling leads to code that seems to be implemented identically to mine).

Comment: `Page is the address of the user buffer` - No, the first argument to `.read_proc` function (of type `read_proc_t`) is **in-kernel** address, to which you may write directly (without `copy_to_user`). After the function returns, the kernel's wrapper will print given information into user space.

Comment: @Tsyvarev you mentioned not using copy_to_user, but my professor is requiring me to use copy_to_user. Is there an alternate function that would be better suited to do this?

Comment: I was able to implement it using memcpy, I may have misread the project and will ask for clarification. Thank you!

Comment: @jww: You refer to docs for `__copy_to_user` function, but the code in the question uses `copy_to_user` one, which performs all needed checks by itself.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to `.read_proc` function (of type `read_proc_t`) is actually **in-kernel address**. You may write to this address directly, and shouldn't use `copy_to_user` for that.

---

You, probably, confuse your function with `.read` function in `file_operations` structure. That function has signature

```
ssize_t (*read) (struct file *, char __user *, size_t, loff_t *);
```

and its second argument is actually pointer to the user-space (thus it has `__user` specifier), for which `copy_to_user` should be used.

Note, that the first argument for your function doesn't have `__user` specifier:

```
typedef int (read_proc_t)(char *page, char **start, off_t off,
          int count, int *eof, void *data);
```